# I'm trying to add a new icon svg for a collapsible row in .liquid for a shopify theme

Tags: css, svg, liquid, shopify-template

I'm currently editing a shopify theme to include a new icon for a collapsible row in the product template theme. I have the icon I want in PNG and a SVG file but I can't figure out how to add the file into the icon-accordion.liquid. I have been searching for answers for hours and shopify is worse than useless in have any answers.

I did add this into the main-product.liquid but that's pretty much all that I've accomplished.

```
"value": "Textile",       "label":"t:sections.mainproduct.blocks.collapsible_tab.settings.icon.options__44.label"
            },
```

What really is stumping me is I don't under stand how the <path d= works in the icon-accordion.liquid file and how to get those values for my svg. Please can anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

The `icon-accordion.liquid` file is a snippet. That snippet checks for the value given by the option selected.

The `<svg>` code from your SVG can be obtained if you open the SVG file in a code editor, alternatively there are online tools that can extract the code. The one I like to use in [svgomg](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/) by jakearchibald on GitHub.

Once you have the SVG code, you can add a new *option* in the snippet, by adding a new `{%- when 'Textile' -%}` line and then pasting the SVG code below it.

Comment: You are literally my hero! I've been combing the internet and trying everything I found or could think of to no avail.  Thank you, thank you, thank you!

Comment: @Algebruh Glad to help, if you can, please Accept this answer so it can be marked as complete :D